# Decoupling the data to be manipulated from the proofs that the manipulations are justified

Tags: coq

I have a type of lists whose heads and tails must be in a certain sense "compatible":

```
Inductive tag := A | B. (* Just an example *)

Inductive element : tag -> tag -> Set :=
  | AA : element A A
  | AB : element A B
  | BB : element B B. (* Also just an example *)

Inductive estack : tag -> tag -> Set :=
  | ENil  : forall     t,                              estack t t
  | ECons : forall r s t, element r s -> estack s t -> estack r t.
```

However, I do not like this code very much, for the following reasons:

1. It is not *modular*: The ad-hoc list data constructors are intrinsically coupled with the proofs that the heads and tails are compatible - the tags.
2. It does not favor *code reuse*: I am forced to redefine the usual list functions (such as list concatenation) and re-prove the usual list theorems (such as the associativity of list concatenation).

I have a different approach in mind, which consists of three steps:

1. Defining a single type of tagged elements (as opposed to a family of tagged types of elements):

   ```
   Inductive taggedElement := Tagged : forall t1 t2, element t1 t2 -> taggedElement.
   ```
2. Defining the type of arbitrary (that is, either valid or invalid) lists of tagged elements:

   ```
   Definition taggedElementStack := list taggedElement.
   ```
3. Defining a *valid* list of tagged elements as a tuple whose elements are an arbitrary list of tagged elements *and* a proof that the elements are compatible with the adjacent ones.

   ```
   (* I have no idea how to do this in Coq, hence the question!
    * 
    * I am going to use pseudomathematical notation. I am not well versed in either
    * mathematics or theoretical computer science, so please do not beat me with a
    * stick if I say something that is completely bogus!
    * 
    * I want to construct the type
    * 
    *     (tes : taggedElementStack, b : proof that P(tes) holds)
    * 
    * where P(tes) is a predicate that is only true when, for every sublist of tes,
    * including tes itself, the heads and tails are compatible.
    *)
   ```

How would I perform the third step in Coq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `estack`, what does it do?  Generalize!  `element` is just a relation (`A -> A -> Set`), `tag` is just a `Set`.  What do you get?

```
Inductive RTList {I : Set} (X : Rel I) : Rel I :=
  | RTNil  : forall {i : I}, RTList X i i
  | RTCons : forall {i j k : I},    X i j -> RTList X j k -> RTList X i k.
```

(`Rel` ist just a Definition with `Rel I = I -> I -> Set`.)

Reflexive-transitive closure!  That *is* common, reusable and modular. Or so you'd think.

The only implementation I found in Coq's libs is in `Coq.Relations.Relation_Operators`, named [`clos_refl_trans`](http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Relations.Relation_Operators.html#clos_refl_trans), differently structured and locked into `Prop` (all according to the docs, didn't try it).

You'll probably have to re-implement that or find a library somewhere.  At least, you'll only have to do this once (or up to three times for `Set`, `Prop` and `Type`).

---

Your other idea will probably be harder to manage.  Look at [`NoDup`](http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Lists.List.html#NoDup) for something that's similar to your description, you might be able to reuse the pattern.  If you really want that.  [`NoDup`](http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Lists.List.html#NoDup) uses [`In`](http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Lists.List.html#In), which is a function that checks if an element is in a list.  The last time I tried using it, I found it considerably harder to solve proofs involving `In`.  You can't just `destruct` but have to apply helper lemmas, you have to carefully unfold exactly $n levels, folding back is hard etc. etc.  I'd suggest that unless it's truly necessary, you'd better stick with data types for `Prop`s.